# How to confirm if a site is using Device Fingerprinting

Tags: web-browser, cookies, chrome, firefox, user-tracking

Is it possible to confirm if a site is using Device Fingerprinting? When the site owner uses JavaScript, is there something we can look for in the script to confirm if a website is using device fingerprinting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless they are pulling in a known off the shelf fingerprinting script you would have to look at what their client side code is doing.

Probing for available fonts and add-ins isn't necessarily malicious - both can be for improving user experience. Generating a list of all of them a sending it up to a server is more suspicious.

Instead passing the list locally through a hash function and sending the result to a server is almost certainly fingerprinting (I can't think of a single non-fingerprinting use case for this).

If you are asking about detecting fingerprinting automatically I'd suggest the best you could do is looking for segments of known fingerprinting code or communication with known fingerprinting services.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already accepted the previous answer but I think I might be able to offer you some help. There is a Canadian VPN company I personally use called TunnelBear. They originally started as just a VPN but have now heavily branched out to other consumer computer security tools and they do make a Google Chrome plugin that is an ad-blocker that doubles as a strong privacy protection tool.

One of its many features includes detection of browser fingerprinting and the ability to thwart it (I am assuming via generating fake data for the finger printer to pick up). If memory serves me correctly, this plugin is also totally free to use, you can check it out here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tunnelbear-blocker/bebdhgdigjiiamnkcenegafmfjoghafk?hl=en

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

## The answer is:

Yes there is a way! Is it generally obvious, but legislatively hard to prove. I know there is an organization that is working actually on a system to list all the vendors who uses browser fingerprinting and persistent cookies, but this project still in development. So, you would have to do it as below by yourself so far.

## How to see if a site is using Device Fingerprinting?

1. Use the web developer tool with Chrome in order to list all the network traffic
   *To make it appears, press F12*
2. Select the tab "Network"
3. Click on the button "Reload"
4. Inspect all the `POST` traffic
   *This is how you transfer your personal information to the vendors*
5. Search for one `POST` sniffing all your JavaScript attributes, using `.swf` files against your consent, or any other massive data transfer from the client side to the vendors network. If you found some, that means you are fingerprinted my friend.

## I am fingerprinted, now what to do?

Actually, EFF, GDRP, e-Privacy, Cookie Law and soon the Brexit regulations are working hard against this type of practice. Since the May 25th, 2018, using persistent cookies is now prohibited! As the clients need to consent the usage of cookie before vendors can use them, reproducing cookies when the client express the desire the delete them is totally against that principle. If you delete a cookie and it is reappearing without any consent, please report this vendor's website to the privacy regulation applies into your nation.

[image]